# How to use pd.to_datetime to retrieve dates from user input of a future date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, user-input, streamlit

The following code allows me to select dates to visualise and predict stock prices in a defined date range

```
start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2021-11-20'

st.title('Stock Prediction')

ticker_input = st.sidebar.text_input('Enter Stock Ticker', 'AAPL')
df = data.DataReader(ticker_input, 'yahoo', start, end)
st.subheader(ticker_input)
```

The code only works when I change the end variable to a future date within the IDE by changing `end` to `'2022-01-01'` and then run it in streamlit. My prediction chart would also change to reflect the end date. How can I change the end variable so the user can select future dates themselves? The tutorial I followed doesn't show this and I've tried to look at examples where datetime lets users select dates in the future and they all seem to just go up to present day.

```
start = st.date_input('Start', value = pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01'))
end = st.date_input('End', value = pd.to_datetime('2024-01-01'))
```

I tried using `pd.to_datetime` and `st.date_input` like this to see if the user can change it from the dropdown calendar but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `st`? A module?

Comment: yeah streamlit library, used for making web applications for data science projects

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the problem? If I understand correctly - the date_input doesn't work like you expect it to and
**the user cannot change the date to future dates**, right?

Answer (score 0):

First i would like to point out that pandas-datareader does not predict stock prices it enables you to get historical data about the stock prices for example yahoo. This mean that the maximum end date can be today and giving it a larger date will not change the data returned from calling:

```
data.DataReader(ticker_input, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

For more you can read their [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo).

That in mind here is the code to get a user to input start date and end date and plot a stock prices plot:

```
import streamlit as st
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime

###########
# sidebar #
###########
#
ticker_input = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select one symbol', ('AAPL',))
# create default date range
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1)
# ask user for his date
start_date = st.sidebar.date_input('Start date', start)
end_date = st.sidebar.date_input('End date', end)
# validate start_date date is smaller then end_date
if start_date < end_date:
    st.sidebar.success('Start date: `%s`\n\nEnd date:`%s`' % (start_date, end_date))
else:
    st.sidebar.error('Error: End date must fall after start date.')

##############
# Main Panel #
##############
# add title
st.title('Stock Prediction')
# get data based on dates
df = data.DataReader(ticker_input, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
# plot
st.line_chart(df.loc[:, ["Close", "Open", "Low", "High"]])
```